# Setting up GitlabCI stage to run manually as well as execute only on merge request

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I have a requirement of manually pushing the images to nexus and at same time during merge request it shouldn't be manual , it must automatically triggers the push to registry stage without any manual intervention.

Tried with all possible all rules for push to registry stage it triggers either automatically for all commit or its manual.

Current rules as below

rules:

```
- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  when: always
- when: manual
```

Anyone can help on this .